# I am using ZXingObjC lib for reading barcode from an image but its not returing any result the code i am using is below

Tags: iphone, xcode4, iso

```
-(void)decode:(CVImageBufferRef)BufferRef
{

  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  CGImageRef videoFrameImage = [ZXCGImageLuminanceSource createImageFromBuffer:BufferRef];

  CGImageRef rotatedImage = [self rotateImage:videoFrameImage degrees:0.0f];

  [NSMakeCollectable(videoFrameImage) autorelease];

  //Decoding:
  ZXLuminanceSource* source = [[[ZXCGImageLuminanceSource alloc]     initWithCGImage:rotatedImage] autorelease];

  [NSMakeCollectable(rotatedImage) autorelease];

  ZXBinaryBitmap* bitmap = [ZXBinaryBitmap binaryBitmapWithBinarizer:[ZXHybridBinarizer binarizerWithSource:source]];

  NSError* error = nil;

  // There are a number of hints we can give to the reader, including

  // possible formats, allowed lengths, and the string encoding.

  ZXDecodeHints* hints = [ZXDecodeHints hints];

  ZXMultiFormatReader* reader = [ZXMultiFormatReader reader];

  ZXResult* result = [reader decode:bitmap
                              hints:hints
                              error:&error];
  if (result) 
  {

    // The coded result as a string. The raw data can be accessed with

    // result.rawBytes and result.length.

    NSString* contents = result.text;

    // The barcode format, such as a QR code or UPC-A

    ZXBarcodeFormat format = result.barcodeFormat;

  } 

  else 

  {

    // Use error to determine why we didn't get a result, such as a barcode

    // not being found, an invalid checksum, or a format inconsistency.
  }


  [pool drain];

}
```

Comment: As of Mar. 21 2013, ZXingObjC has a memory leak

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem which is easily resolved by down sampling the image that the camera generates.   Apparently it's too high res for the library to process the bar code out of it.   By reducing the size of my UIImage to 640x480 before call [image CGImage] everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Right, the ZXing scan from image is not perfect. I use several predefined resolution to scale image to. ```NSArray  *sizes = @[[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(480.f, 480.f)], [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(640.f, 640.f)],[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(640.f, 480.f)]]; for (NSValue *value in sizes) {//scale to value.CGSizeValue and decode};```

Answer (score 0):

You've commented that you should use the error to determine why you didn't get a result, but you don't actually do that.  Look at what's in `error`.

Comment: I saw the error its always giving "A barcode was not found in this image" but there is a barcode in the image i am not getting what to do please help.